# Alloy syntax for remainder types?

Tags: alloy

Is there a direct way to represent a remainder type in Alloy, rather than having to subtract the union all subtypes explicitly? For instance, in:

```
sig Test {}
one sig A, B extends Test {}
```

I'd like to be able to refer to the expression `Test-(A+B)` via shorthand that doesn't need to change every time `Test` gets extended by a new sig. Although this would only be syntactic sugar, it could help me avoid mistakes when refactoring models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce a set that represents the remainder as follows:

```
abstract sig Test {}
sig Remainder extends Test {}
one sig A, B extends Test {}
```

This will partition the set of `Test` atoms into three subsets, with `Remainder` being equivalent to `Test - (A + B)`. If you later decide to extend `Test` by adding `one sig C`, for example, `Remainder` will still give you the remainder set.

Comment: Obvious in hindsight! Thanks, Eunsuk.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Alloy in a while, but I don't think it is possible the way you want it. However, you can refactor the union to just one place in the model. Example:

```
sig Test {}
one sig A, B extends Test {}

fun Remainder : set Test {
    Test - (A+B)
}

run { some Remainder } for 5
```

You define a relation, using a function, here called `Remainder`, that is defined by subtracting the union of all subtypes from the base type.
Everytime you add a new subtype to the model, just remember to add it to the definition of `Remainder` as well and you're good to go.

Throughout the model, you can just refer to `Remainder` to get all *pure* `Test` atoms, just as I used in the anonymous predicate in the `run` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the definition to hold whatever the new sigs extending `Test` are introduced, you can use Alloy's little known [meta capabilities](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/meta.html), that allow you to iterate through sigs through a special set `sig$`.

E.g., you can do something like:

```
fun Remainder [] : set Test {
  {t : Test | all sig : sig$ | sig = Test$ || t not in sig.value}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to meta atoms. I had not seen them before.